# Does ANOVA work with percentages, like Conversion Rate?

Tags: anova, dunnett

I'm trying to figure out if I can perform ANOVA on conversion rate. Would this work?

Editing for more information: The question we are trying to solve is for our AB Testing program. Oftentimes we have multiple variants within our tests, and we are measuring conversion rate (expressed as orders / unique visitors). Is ANOVA a possible solution in this case, where our values our percentages?

Also, would I be able to apply Dunnett's Correction on conversion rates as well?

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at your data.  That being said, you are probably better off performing a logistic regression.  Can you tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish though?  This post will likely not receive any good answers without more details.

Comment: Sure, I can edit my original post too. I'm working with conversion rates as the main value, which we calculate as orders/ unique visitors. Typically expressed as a percentage, for this example we can say 3%. I'm trying to look at each percent by day, for each variant we are testing (The goal is up to 10) and calculate whether these conversion rates are significantly different from one another. Not sure of the best way of doing that

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've said in your comment, it would be hard to justify using ANOVA with percentages given you have a lot of values at the extremes (close to 0% or 100% within different groups).  Instead, I would encourage  you to model the data with binary logistic regression, where each conversion is coded 1 and each non-conversion is coded 0.  You can then specify *apriori* contrasts that you would want to test for each of your treatment groups (it may be for example that comparing certain treatments against one another offers little or no value).  Of course, this presupposes that you have the raw data (i.e. for each visitor you know the treatment(s) he received and whether or not he converted).

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense. Could you elaborate a bit on what you mean "specifying contrasts you would want to test." Would this be like deciding a certain amount of uplift that would be valid to test? Say, we would want to check if there was an increase of 2%? Or am I off base there?

Comment: What I mean by specifying contrasts, is that you would want to specify the combinations ahead of time of different treatments that you want to test.  For example if you have 5 treatments, treatment A, B, C, D, and E, you might only be interested in every combination of A against all other variables, but nothing else (e.g. maybe you are not interested in looking at the differences between B and C?).  Search here for logistic regression and contrasts and you should find some helpful post.

Comment: For example:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235402/interpreting-logistic-regression-and-contrasts-in-r,

or

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-create-contrasts-with-proc-logistic/

or

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60817/significance-of-categorical-predictor-in-logistic-regression

Comment: Ah, makes sense. We'd only primarily be comparing against the control, so treatment A in your example. Thanks for that link, very helpful.