# Hypothesis testing of a slope in simple linear regression

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

In simple linear regression, one can perform hypothesis testing
$$H_0: \beta = 0  \ \text{against} \ H_1: \beta \neq 0$$
where $\beta$ is the slope of the fitted regression line, obtained by least-square method. In R, we can use the command `summary` to see the p-value of this test. This p-value is obtained by computing
$2P(T > |t|)$ and the t-score $t$ can also be seen in `summary` ($T$ has $t$-distribution with $n-2$ degrees of freedom).

Now, consider the following situation:
We have $t > 0$, and we would like to test whether the slope is indeed positive. Is it allowed to change the alternative hypothesis to $H_1: \beta > 0$? So then we compute the p-value by computing $P(T > t)$?

I do know that we can, for instance, look at the estimated $\beta$ and check the p-value in `summary`. If the estimated $\beta$ is also positive, then with a certain significance level we can either reject $H_0$ or not.

Comment: Are you asking if this can be done in R, or are you asking how to perform the significance test with the output of `summary`?  [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325354/if-and-how-to-use-one-tailed-testing-in-multiple-regression) question may be helpful.

Comment: @DemetriPananos I am asking whether I am allowed to compute the p-value manually, by computing $P(T >t)$ to test $H_0: \beta = 0$ against $H_1: \beta > 0$ instead of $H_1: \beta \neq 0$, which is the default of "summary" in R.

Comment: Yea I see no harm in that.  See the linked question in my previous comment

Comment: You can find more duplicates by searching our site for [one-tailed regression tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+one+tail*+test).