# Left tailed t-test in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test

My is $H_0: \beta = 0$ and
my $H1: \beta <0$

I want to run a regression in Rstudio and do this with the following command:

```
model <- lm(Y~independentvariables) 
summary(model)
```

However, I get the t-value of the right tail but my hypothesis is the opposite. I mean that I want the t-value of the left tail.
I was wondering which argument I should add to obtain this?
I hope someone can help me with this..

Answer (score 1):

The p-values in `summary(model)` are for the two-sided hypothesis test, not for the right tailed test. You can perform the one-sided test by calculating the p-value for it. From the summary, you can obtain the t-statistic sa `t.st` and the degrees of freedom say `df.t`, and then use:

```
pt(t.st, df = df.t, lower = TRUE)
```

This will give you the p-value for the left tailed test.

More details here: [If and how to use one-tailed testing in multiple regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325354/if-and-how-to-use-one-tailed-testing-in-multiple-regression)